# MongoError: database names cannot contain the character ' ' when using mongoosejs connect to mLab

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Here is my JS code:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'); 

mongoose.connect("mongodb://myUsername:myPassword@ds161039.mlab.com:61039/accounttest");
```

and here is the error when I start server

```
C:\Users\Qk Lahpita\Desktop\server_node_2\node_modules\mongodb\lib\db.js:1774
if(databaseName.indexOf(invalidChars[i]) != -1) throw MongoError.create({message: "database names cannot contain the character '" + invalidChars[i] + "'", driver:true});
                                                ^
MongoError: database names cannot contain the character ' '
at Function.MongoError.create (C:\Users\Qk Lahpita\Desktop\server_node_2\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\error.js:31:11)
at validateDatabaseName (C:\Users\Qk Lahpita\Desktop\server_node_2\node_modules\mongodb\lib\db.js:1774:70)
at new Db (C:\Users\Qk Lahpita\Desktop\server_node_2\node_modules\mongodb\lib\db.js:154:3)
at NativeConnection.doOpen (C:\Users\Qk Lahpita\Desktop\server_node_2\node_modules\mongoose\lib\drivers\node-mongodb-native\connection.js:55:15)
at NativeConnection.Connection._open (C:\Users\Qk Lahpita\Desktop\server_node_2\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:531:15)
at C:\Users\Qk Lahpita\Desktop\server_node_2\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:289:11
at new Promise.ES6 (C:\Users\Qk Lahpita\Desktop\server_node_2\node_modules\mongoose\lib\promise.js:45:3)
at NativeConnection.Connection.open (C:\Users\Qk Lahpita\Desktop\server_node_2\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:288:17)
at Mongoose.connect (C:\Users\Qk Lahpita\Desktop\server_node_2\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:242:47)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Qk Lahpita\Desktop\server_node_2\server.js:36:10)
at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
at Module.runMain (module.js:605:10)
```

My database's name is "accounttest", not contain ' ' character. Why do I have this error and how can I fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried connecting to a different database, or without the database name?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is your database name itself. You should not have spaces in it.

Example

```
const databaseName = "Users"
const connectionURI = "mongodb://127.0.0.1"

MongoClient.connect(connectionURI,{useUnifiedTopology:true},(err,client) => {
if(err) return log("Unable to connect to database");
log("Database Connected")

const db = client.db(databaseName);
```

then you can do whatever you intended to Example :

```
db.addUser("John","kio")
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that `myUsername` and `myPassword` aren't your real values. If your username or password contains some of the special characters, it's possible that you will have to encode them. If that is the case, try something like this:

```
mongoClient.connect("mongodb://myEncodedUsername:myEncodedPassword@ds161039.mlab.com:61039/accounttest", {uri_decode_auth: true}, function(err, db) {
});
```

Comment: my username only has lower and upper character a-z, my password only has lower character a-z and number. Both of them don't have special charecter :(

Answer (score -1):

1.create a database.js file

make a exportble database configuration inside it as follows

```
module.exports = {database : "mongodb://myUsername:myPassword@ds161039.mlab.com:61039/accounttest"};
```

2.Require it to your current JS file

```
var connection = mongoose.connect(config.database);
```