# mongoose useDb error

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to connect to 2 mongodb databases. I have:

```
var db = mongoose.createConnection(config.business_database)
```

then

```
var mongoDB_customer = db.useDb(config.customer_database)
```

My config.business_database looks something like **mongodb://dbname:password@ds111111.mlab.com:11111/hello-world** and same with customer_database **mongodb://dbname:password@ds111111.mlab.com:11111/hello-people** and I am getting an error saying

> database names cannot contain the character '.'

The other question is when this eventually connects, do I still have to use mongoose.connect(db, {})?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42479161/mongoerror-database-names-cannot-contain-the-character-when-using-mongoosej check here.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I only get this error when connecting both databases - individually they both work if connected seperately